# Iterating forward and backward

Tags: list, iterator, rust

We have a double ended list of structs, e.g. `LinkedList`.

I need to iterate forward and backward through the elements (like, 4 times forward then 2 times backward then 5 times forward).

In C++ it would be:

```cpp
iter++; iter++; ... iter--; ...
```

In Rust, I only see `.next()` and `.rev()` which is inconvenient (since after a few iterations I already do not know in which direction I've reversed iteration).

Comment: actually `.rev()` probably does not what you expect. It reverses the iterator, so you are now taking elements from the back.

Comment: Note: in C++ you should use pre-increment/pre-decrement, it varies from slightly more to much more efficient depending on the iterator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) is similar to [`ForwardIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) of C++. What you want is a [`BidirectionalIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), but Rust does not provide a trait similar to it because of a limitation in the type system.

As [Matthieu M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147192/matthieu-m) said in comments, the way an iterator is defined allows a reference to the yielded element to be kept. And that's a problem if the iterator produces mutable references, because moving forward and backward would allow multiples mutable references to the same element. One way to solve this problem would be to tie the lifetime of the yielded element with `&mut self`, so a call to `next` (or `prev`) would borrow `self`, but there is no way of doing it in a generic way (there is a [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1598) to add such capability).

Looking the `Iterator` trait definition:

```
pub trait Iterator {
    type Item;
    fn next<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>;
    // ...
}
```

we can see that the lifetime of `Self::Item` is independent of `'a`. What is necessary to solve the problem is:

```
pub trait Iterator {
    type Item<'a>; // hypothetical syntax
    fn next<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Option<Self::Item<'a>>;
    // ...
}
```

but that is not supported yet.

---

That said, one option is to use a external crate that use a specific iterator (that is, do not implement a trait). The [`linked_list`](https://crates.io/crates/linked-list) crate provides a linked list implementation with [`Cursor`](http://contain-rs.github.io/linked-list/linked_list/struct.Cursor.html), that allows forward and backward iteration:

```
use linked_list::LinkedList;
use std::iter::FromIterator;

fn main() {
    // LinkedList::cursor takes &mut self, so lst must be mutable
    let mut lst = LinkedList::from_iter(0..10);
    let mut c = lst.cursor();

    c.next();
    c.next();
    c.next();
    c.prev();

    assert_eq!(1, *c.prev().unwrap());
}
```

`Cursor` does not allow a reference to the yielded element to be kept. The docs says:

> A `Cursor` is like an iterator, except that it can freely seek back-and-forth, and can safely mutate the list during iteration. This is because the lifetime of its yielded references is tied to its own lifetime, instead of just the underlying list. This means cursors cannot yield multiple elements at once.

The following example:

```
let a = c.next();
let b = c.next();
```

generates this error:

```
error: cannot borrow `c` as mutable more than once at a time [E0499]
    let b = c.next();
```

This happens because `next` (and `prev`) borrows from `self`, that is:

```
fn next<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Option<&'a mut T>
```

Comment: The reason is simply aliasing vs mutability. `Iterator` is designed so that you can retain references to the elements that it yielded, so that if you can go back and forth you would be able to have multiple references to the same element (aka: aliasing). Now, imagine that the references in question are mutable: you now have multiple mutable references to the same element, BOOM. So, since yielding mutable references is desirable, the `Iterator` trait has given up aliasing.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to implement your own iterator to do this. Here's a sample implementation of one for `Vec`s:

```
pub trait ForwardBackwardIterator : Iterator {
    fn prev(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>;
}

pub struct VectorForwardBackwardIterator<'a, Item> where Item : 'a {
    index: Option<usize>,
    vector: &'a Vec<Item>,
}

impl<'a, Item> VectorForwardBackwardIterator<'a, Item> {
    fn new(vector: &'a Vec<Item>) -> VectorForwardBackwardIterator<'a, Item> {
        VectorForwardBackwardIterator { index: None, vector: vector }
    }
}

impl<'a, Item> Iterator for VectorForwardBackwardIterator<'a, Item> {
    type Item = &'a Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a Item> {
        let index = 
            match self.index {
                Some(i) => i + 1,
                None => 0
            };

        self.index = Some(index);
        self.vector.get(index)
    }
}

impl<'a, Item> ForwardBackwardIterator for VectorForwardBackwardIterator<'a, Item> {
    fn prev(&mut self) -> Option<&'a Item> {
        let index = 
            match self.index {
                Some(0) | None => return None,
                Some(i) => i - 1
            };

        self.index = Some(index);
        self.vector.get(index)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let mut iterator = VectorForwardBackwardIterator::new(&v);

    println!("{:?}", iterator.next());
    println!("{:?}", iterator.next());
    println!("{:?}", iterator.next());
    println!("{:?}", iterator.prev());
    println!("{:?}", iterator.prev());
}
```

This prints out

```
Some(0)
Some(1)
Some(2)
Some(1)
Some(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation allows you to create a `List` from an iterator using the `from_iter` function, and to convert a `List` into an iterator using the `into_iter` function. The `IntoIter` type is an iterator that consumes the `List`, and the `next` method returns the elements of the list in the same order that they were inserted.

```
use std::mem;
use std::ptr;
use std::iter::{self, FromIterator};

struct Node<T> {
    elem: T,
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    prev: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

struct List<T> {
    head: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    tail: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

struct Iter<'a, T> {
    head: Option<&'a Box<Node<T>>>,
    tail: Option<&'a Box<Node<T>>>,
    rev: bool,
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.rev {
            self.tail.map(|node| {
                self.tail = node.prev.as_ref();
                &node.elem
            })
        } else {
            self.head.map(|node| {
                self.head = node.next.as_ref();
                &node.elem
            })
        }
    }
}

impl<T> List<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        List { head: None, tail: None }
    }

    fn iter(&self) -> Iter<T> {
        Iter {
            head: self.head.as_ref(),
            tail: self.tail.as_ref(),
            rev: false,
        }
    }

    fn iter_rev(&self) -> Iter<T> {
        Iter {
            head: self.tail.as_ref(),
            tail: self.head.as_ref(),
            rev: true,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> FromIterator<T> for List<T> {
    fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item=T>>(iter: I) -> Self {
        let mut list = List::new();
        for elem in iter {
            list.push_back(elem);
        }
        list
    }
}

impl<T> IntoIterator for List<T> {
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = IntoIter<T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        IntoIter { list: self }
    }
}

struct IntoIter<T> {
    list: List<T>,
}

impl<T> Iterator for IntoIter<T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.list.pop_front()
    }
}
```